# Creating a new column in R conditioned on the values in a different column and different row

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, lapply, sapply

I'm trying to figure out how to create a new column in an R dataframe whose values are based on the values in another column, but in a different row. My data is as follows:

```
player <- c('Tim Duncan', 'Lebron James', 'Kobe Bryant', 'Paul Pierce',
            'Tim Duncan', 'Lebron James', 'Kobe Bryant', 'Paul Pierce',
            'Tim Duncan', 'Lebron James', 'Kobe Bryant', 'Paul Pierce')
t <- c(3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
min_per_game <-  c(30, 36, 34, 33, 31, 36, 34, 32, 29, 35, 32, 36)
pts_per_36_min <- c(19, 28, 27, 24, 22, 27, 25, 28, 23, 28, 29, 29)

df <- data.frame(player, t, min_per_game, pts_per_36_min)
```

What I want to do is create a new column called "pts_per_game" that will look at each row in the dataframe, examine the value in the 't' column, then go find the row that has an equivalent value in the 'player' column but a value in the 't' column that is smaller by 1, and then fill the new "pts_per_game" column using data from the row that R has identified (specifically min_per_game/36 * pts_per_36 min).

So for example, in the first row of this dataframe, the value in the 'player' column is "Tim Duncan" and the value in the "t" column is 3. I want R to see that, go find the row where 'player == "Tim Duncan" and t == 2, take the data from that row and do ((min_per_game/36)* pts_per_36 min), and then put the resulting value in the first dataframe row (where player is Tim Duncan and t is 3) in a new column called "pts_per_game". And I want it do loop through the whole dataframe and do that for every row, with an understanding that this means that rows with the lowest possible value of t (1, in this case), will not be able to have a "pts_per_game" value computed for them, and thus should receive NA. Can anyone help me figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You may try using `dplyr::lead`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  arrange(player, desc(t)) %>%
  group_by(player) %>%
  mutate(pts_per_game = lead(min_per_game)/36 * lead(pts_per_36_min))

   player           t min_per_game pts_per_36_min pts_per_game
   <chr>        <dbl>        <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 Kobe Bryant      3           34             27         23.6
 2 Kobe Bryant      2           34             25         25.8
 3 Kobe Bryant      1           32             29         NA  
 4 Lebron James     3           36             28         27  
 5 Lebron James     2           36             27         27.2
 6 Lebron James     1           35             28         NA  
 7 Paul Pierce      3           33             24         24.9
 8 Paul Pierce      2           32             28         29  
 9 Paul Pierce      1           36             29         NA  
10 Tim Duncan       3           30             19         18.9
11 Tim Duncan       2           31             22         18.5
12 Tim Duncan       1           29             23         NA
```

## This also works

```
data.frame(player, t, min_per_game, pts_per_36_min) %>%
  arrange(player, desc(t)) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(player) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(pts_per_game = dplyr::lead(min_per_game)/36 * dplyr::lead(pts_per_36_min))
```

Comment: When I try the above, I get the error message "Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')""

Comment: @ben_p_4370 Does same error occurs with `dplyr::mutate`?

Comment: It does, yes, same error

Comment: @ben_p_4370 Does `df` you're using is `df <- data.frame(player, t, min_per_game, pts_per_36_min)`?

Comment: Yes. I also tried your suggested solution on my much larger actual data set I'm trying to do this with (the df example I provided above was just a way to summarize the issue for stack overflow) and I get the same UseMethod error in both cases

Comment: @ben_p_4370 Would you give me the result of `str(df)`?

Comment: `'data.frame': 12 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ player        : chr  "Tim Duncan" "Lebron James" "Kobe Bryant" "Paul Pierce" ...
 $ t             : num  3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ min_per_game  : num  30 36 34 33 31 36 34 32 29 35 ...
 $ pts_per_36_min: num  19 28 27 24 22 27 25 28 23 28 ...`

Comment: @ben_p_4370 I'll try to reproduce your error. Please wait just for a moment.

Comment: Is it because dplyr::mutate operates on dataframes but we've given it individual vectors here (min_per_game and pts_per_36_min)?

Comment: @ben_p_4370 No, that may not be the problem. In new session that only including `dplyr`, it also did not print any error. What is the version of `dplyr`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239467/discussion-between-park-and-ben-p-4370).